# Notation to make a negative answer equal 0

Tags: notation

So basically, I'm making a big equation, and one component of it is this

$$(n-5)+(n-7)$$

The *n*-value can be anything from 1 to far away. So, that obviously leads to some negative numbers. However, this part of the equation is only applicable whenever the *n*-value is greater than the subtracting numbers (respectively). So, is there some kind of notation I can use to signal that if the answer is a negative number, then it is to be dismissed, or just turned to 0? A kind of notation similar to the ceiling and floor functions, where a non-integer is turned to the closest integer (either up or down).

Comment: How about $\max (X, 0)$?

Comment: @lulu How would one format-wise integrate that into the equation?

Comment: Machine learning folks call this the "relu" function :)

Comment: Depends on the equation.  You said it was ok to replace the given expression, which I'm calling $X$, with $0$ (if $X<0$) and that's what my term does.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I don't understand. Could you perhaps write it? Would it be something like $$(n-5)+(n-7) max(X,0)$$

Comment: I have written it.  Not sure what you don't understand.  I am just calling your expression $X$ to keep it general...is that what is confusing you?  In your case you'd have $\max ((n-5)+(n-7),0)$.

Comment: @lulu Aha, I see, that was what I was looking for. I don't understand the formatting behind the "operator" though (I'm calling it that because I don't know the proper terminology). What does the "max" refer to, and why is there a $0$?

Comment: Could an alternative notation be $$((n-5)+(n-7))^+$$ @lulu?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that notation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The written notation would be
$$
X(n) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        (n-5)+(n-7) & n \ge 6\\
        0 & n<6
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
In the comments were given notations that can be used in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* in this case.

\begin{align*}
\left((n-5)+(n-7)\right)\color{blue}{[[n\geq 6]]}:=
\begin{cases}2n-12&\qquad n\geq 6\\0&\qquad n< 6\end{cases}
\end{align*}